# Nested Loop C# Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm new here in stack overflow and basically new in coding c#. I want to code a symbol from the comboBox with numbers of rows and column that I will input.
Can I have a tip?
for example, I want the symbol "#" to be display in the label5 with the rows of 5 and columns of 6.

this is my code:

```cs
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text); k++)
        {
            label5.Text = comboBox1.Text + k + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, have a look at line

```
 label5.Text = comboBox1.Text + k + " ";
```

you *assign* `comboBox1.Text + k + " "` to `label5.Text` which means that you *drop* its old
value and put the new one. That's why all the loops except the last will be for nothing.
Let's collect all the lines. Technically, you can put

```
 label5.Text += comboBox1.Text + k + " ";
```

However, a better approach is

```
 using System.Text;

 ... 

 // We don't want constanly parse textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text; let's do it once
 int colCount = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
 int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

 // We are going to build the string in a loop; let's do it efficiently 
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 // As I can see, you don't use i variable; 
 for (int row = 0; k <= rowCount; ++row) {
   // If we have anything, we should add a new line 
   if (sb.Length > 0)
     sb.AppendLine();

   // Guess: you want comboBox1.Text once in each line
   sb.Append({comboBox1.Text});

   // Here we create columns
   for (int col = 0; col <= colCount; ++col) {
     sb.Append($" {col} ");
 }     

 // Finally, we assing the text built to the label  
 label5.Text = sb.ToString();
```